# Mark py.test test with requirement ID

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use custom markers for my test cases to mark them with the requirement IDs.

```
@pytest.mark.req_id("4")
def test_startup(...):
    ...
```

This is working but i now want to select only this test by using the command line option -k.

```
py.test -v -k "req_id=='4'"
```

But my test is not recognized.

I could use a custom command line option with a list of requirement ids to be tested but i want to know if this is possible using the existing command line options because it would be more flexible.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to pytest manual [Marking test functions and selecting them for a run](https://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run) you'd better use `-m` option to select test cases based on marker. The selection is based on the marker name.

If you change your marker naming scheme to include the IDs in the name, then selection can be done like this:

```
@pytest.mark.req_id_4
def test_startup(...):

py.test -m req_id_4
```